# Why does not Rasterize work in SciDraw?

Tags: plotting, rasterize, scidraw

In the documentation, it says " Rasterization is requested with Rasterize->True, and the resolution can be specified through the ImageResolution option. "

However, when I try to enable `Rasterize` in the `FigurePanel` to reduce the output file size, I found the plot is actually shifted and become smaller in size. Here is a simple example.

```
Figure[FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}], 
 CanvasSize -> {4, 4}]
```

The plot is just a line:
[image]

However, if I turn on `Rasterize`

```
Figure[FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, 
  Rasterize -> True], CanvasSize -> {4, 4}]
```

The output is weird:
[image]
The line is shrunk inside the frame. Is it the correct way to use `Rasterize->True`?

I am using SciDraw 0.0.7 and Matheamtica 12.0.0 on Windows 10.